# Full screen parallax background

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, parallax

I'm learning how to use the parallax effects using the [jParallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/) jQuery plugin. So far what I have done works fine but I need to make the parallax affect the whole screen. I applied it to the body tag but that doesn't work apparently. [Here](http://kode.co.nf/) is how it looks.

Here's the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.parallax.css" />
<style type="text/css">
.parallax-viewport {
    height:20em;
    max-width:60em;
    width:100%;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.parallax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.event.frame.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#parallax .parallax-layer')
    .parallax({
      mouseport: $('#parallax')
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body id="parallax" class="parallax-viewport">

    <div class="parallax-layer" style="width:600px; height:274px;">
        <img src="images/background_layers/bottom_layer.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax-layer" style="width:1100px; height:284px;">
        <img src="images/background_layers/mid_layer.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax-layer" style="width:1360px; height:320px;">
        <img src="images/background_layers/top_layer.png" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I fill the whole screen with the parallax background?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your .parallax-viewport height from 20em; to 100%

Comment: That was the first thing I tried but it didn't change anything.